# Xpath expression gives multiple values

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the requirement in which I need to match values

**Buyer,BilltoParty,Shipto** which can the value `AGIIS-EBID or EAN or GLN`

I am using XPath1.0 to extract these values and use the condition.

**I am able to get correct value for the Buyer***

The problem I am facing is for Shipto and Billtoparty

Xpath for getting value for Shipto and Billto

```
//*[local-name()='ShipNotice']/*[local-name()='ShipNoticeBody']/*[local-name()='ShipNoticePartners']/*[local-name()='OtherPartner']/*[local-name()='PartnerInformation']/*[local-name()='PartnerIdentifier']/@*[local-name()='Agency']
```

Which gives the value as:

```
Agency AGIIS-EBID
Agency SCAC
Agency AGIIS-EBID
Agency AGIIS-EBID
```

**INPUT XML** Updated one

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:ces:names:specification:ces:schema:all:4:0">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ces:ShipNotice Version="4.0" xmlns:ces="urn:ces:names:specification:ces:schema:all:4:0">
            <ces:Header>
                <ces:From>
                </ces:From>
                <ces:To>
                </ces:To>
            </ces:Header>
            <ces:ShipNoticeBody>
                <ces:ShipNoticePartners>
                    <ces:Buyer>
                        <ces:PartnerInformation>
                            <ces:PartnerIdentifier Agency="AGIIS-EBID">8049915600000</ces:PartnerIdentifier>
                        </ces:PartnerInformation>
                    </ces:Buyer>
                    <ces:OtherPartner PartnerRole="ShipFrom">
                        <ces:PartnerInformation>
                            <ces:PartnerIdentifier Agency="AGIIS-EBID">0447026370000</ces:PartnerIdentifier>
                        </ces:PartnerInformation>
                    </ces:OtherPartner>
                    <ces:OtherPartner PartnerRole="Carrier">
                        <ces:PartnerInformation>
                            <ces:PartnerIdentifier Agency="SCAC">B935</ces:PartnerIdentifier>
                        </ces:PartnerInformation>
                    </ces:OtherPartner>
                    <ces:OtherPartner PartnerRole="ShipTo">
                        <ces:PartnerInformation>
                            <ces:PartnerIdentifier Agency="AGIIS-EBID">8049915600000</ces:PartnerIdentifier>
                        </ces:PartnerInformation>
                    </ces:OtherPartner>
                    <ces:OtherPartner PartnerRole="BillToParty">
                        <ces:PartnerInformation>
                            <ces:PartnerIdentifier Agency="AGIIS-EBID">1024122440000</ces:PartnerIdentifier>
                        </ces:PartnerInformation>
                    </ces:OtherPartner>
                </ces:ShipNoticePartners>
                <ces:ShipNoticeDetails>
                </ces:ShipNoticeDetails>
            </ces:ShipNoticeBody>
        </ces:ShipNotice>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Below is the code I am using.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config" xmlns:cidx="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:4:0" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" extension-element-prefixes="dp">
    <xsl:param name="dpconfig:AGIIS-EBID" select=" 'AGIIS-EBID' "/>
    <xsl:param name="dpconfig:EAN" select="'EAN'"/>
    <xsl:param name="dpconfig:GLN" select="'GLN'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="Buyer" select="//*[local-name()='ShipNotice']/*[local-name()='ShipNoticeBody']/*[local-name()='ShipNoticePartners']/*[local-name()='Buyer']/*[local-name()='PartnerInformation']/*[local-name()='PartnerIdentifier']/@*[local-name()='Agency']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Shipto" select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ShipNotice']/*[local-name()='ShipNoticeBody']/*[local-name()='ShipNoticePartners']/*[local-name()='OtherPartner']/*[local-name()='PartnerInformation']/*[local-name()='PartnerIdentifier']/@*[local-name()='Agency']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Billto" select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ShipNotice']/*[local-name()='ShipNoticeBody']/*[local-name()='ShipNoticePartners']/*[local-name()='OtherPartner']/*[local-name()='PartnerInformation']/*[local-name()='PartnerIdentifier']/@*[local-name()='Agency']"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$Buyer='AGIIS-EBID' and  $Shipto='AGIIS-EBID' and $Billto='AGIIS-EBID' or $Buyer='EAN' and  $Shipto='EAN' and $Billto='EAN' or $Buyer='GLN' and  $Shipto='GLN' and $Billto='GLN'">
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                    Partner didn't match the AGIIS-EBID or EAN or GLN
                </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone please help me on Xpath and also let me know the way I am doing the condition match is correct or not?

**Expecting output**

I am expecting the variables Buyer, Shipto, Billto should match the value == `AGIIS-EBID`, but the Xpath which I am using gives

```
Agency AGIIS-EBID
Agency SCAC
Agency AGIIS-EBID
Agency AGIIS-EBID
```

Comment: you might want to trim down the xml to only the relevant parts if you want to receive an answer.

Comment: what output are you expecting? as you found out, there are multiple matches in your document.

Comment: "*The problem I am facing is for Shipto and Billtoparty*" What exactly is that problem? -- P.S. Is there a reason why you can't use the proper namespace/s in your paths, instead of the horrible `*[local-name()='xyx']` hack?

Comment: @michael.hor257k and remco I am expecting the output to match the value AGIIS-EBID for the variable Buyer,Shipto and Billto. Problem When I use the above Xpath it gives alll values of otherpartner/@Agency values. Namespace always remain ces only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at your XSLT, and seeing that your `Shipto` and `Billto` variables have the same declaration, I think what you are saying is that these currently match four nodes (or rather attributes), but you only want one.

Specifically, from looking at your XML, it looks like the crucial information is on the `OtherPartner` node

```
<ces:OtherPartner PartnerRole="ShipTo">

<ces:OtherPartner PartnerRole="BillToParty">
```

This means you need to add an extra condition after the current condition that matches `OtherPartner`. For example, for `ShipTo` the condition would be this:

```
    <xsl:variable name="Shipto" select="
         /*[local-name()='Envelope']
         /*[local-name()='Body']
         /*[local-name()='ShipNotice']
         /*[local-name()='ShipNoticeBody']
         /*[local-name()='ShipNoticePartners']
         /*[local-name()='OtherPartner'][@PartnerRole='ShipTo']
         /*[local-name()='PartnerInformation']
         /*[local-name()='PartnerIdentifier']
         /@*[local-name()='Agency']"/>
```

Of course, as pointed out in comments, if you know the namespace uri in the XML, it is preferable to declare them in the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config" 
  xmlns:cidx="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:4:0" 
  xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:ces="urn:ces:names:specification:ces:schema:all:4:0" extension-element-prefixes="dp">
```

Then you can "simplify" your variable to this for example

```
<xsl:variable name="Shipto" select="
        soapenv:Envelope
        /soapenv:Body
        /ces:ShipNotice
        /ces:ShipNoticeBody
        /ces:ShipNoticePartners
        /ces:OtherPartner[@PartnerRole='ShipTo']
        /ces:PartnerInformation
        /ces:PartnerIdentifier/@Agency"/>
```

And similary for your `Billto` variable. Just change the condition on the `@PartnerRole` attribute.

Additionally, you might want to consider putting some parentheses around you final condition

```
<xsl:when test="
     ($Buyer='AGIIS-EBID' and  $Shipto='AGIIS-EBID' and $Billto='AGIIS-EBID') 
     or ($Buyer='EAN' and  $Shipto='EAN' and $Billto='EAN') 
     or ($Buyer='GLN' and  $Shipto='GLN' and $Billto='GLN')">
```

Or better still do this...

```
<xsl:when test="($Buyer='AGIIS-EBID' or $Buyer='EAN' or $Buyer='GLN') 
                 and $Shipto=$Buyer 
                 and $Billto=$Buyer">
```

Comment: thanks Tim C. Is that correct long of doing Xpath? Also other requirement I was doing the conditional match. Can you please advise the way I am doing it correct or not?

Comment: Sorry what I meant is Tim the way I am doing the Xpath is correct or any other solution is preferred? Also the thing I wanted to ask is about the conditional match I am doing it.. Is right approach?

Comment: If your current xpath is always giving the answer you want, then it is "correct", and you probably don't need to ask a question on StackOverflow! It is not always possible to give an exact answer as to what is "preferred" though. Having said that, as mentioned in comments, and also in the answer, it is preferable to use proper namespaces in your xpath.

Comment: Note that, if you do have xpath that works, but are looking for a better way to code it, you could perhaps consider asking a question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for valuable inputs