# conditional match for multiple attributes using XSLT

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements

Below is the input XML

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:ces:names:specification:ces:schema:all:4:0">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ces:ShipNotice Version="4.0" xmlns:ces="urn:ces:names:specification:ces:schema:all:4:0">
            <ces:Header>
                <ces:From>
                </ces:From>
                <ces:To>
                </ces:To>
            </ces:Header>
            <ces:ShipNoticeBody>
                <ces:ShipNoticePartners>
                    <ces:Buyer>
                        <ces:PartnerInformation>
                            <ces:PartnerIdentifier Agency="AGIIS-EBID">8049915600000</ces:PartnerIdentifier>
                        </ces:PartnerInformation>
                    </ces:Buyer>
                    <ces:OtherPartner PartnerRole="ShipTo">
                        <ces:PartnerInformation>
                            <ces:PartnerIdentifier Agency="AGIIS-EBID">8049915600000</ces:PartnerIdentifier>
                        </ces:PartnerInformation>
                    </ces:OtherPartner>
                    <ces:OtherPartner PartnerRole="BillToParty">
                        <ces:PartnerInformation>
                            <ces:PartnerIdentifier Agency="AGIIS-EBID">1024122440000</ces:PartnerIdentifier>
                        </ces:PartnerInformation>
                    </ces:OtherPartner>
                </ces:ShipNoticePartners>
                <ces:ShipNoticeDetails>
                </ces:ShipNoticeDetails>
            </ces:ShipNoticeBody>
        </ces:ShipNotice>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to test for incoming request if the value of **Buyer and  Shipto and Billtoparty** can be **AGIIS-EBID or EAN**.

I did ask similar question before 
[Previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332660/xpath-expression-gives-multiple-values)

In previous thread the value I was testing was same.

```
<xsl:when test="
 ($Buyer='AGIIS-EBID' and  $Shipto='AGIIS-EBID' and $Billto='AGIIS-EBID') 
 or ($Buyer='EAN' and  $Shipto='EAN' and $Billto='EAN') 
 or ($Buyer='GLN' and  $Shipto='GLN' and $Billto='GLN')">
```

My question is how to test the condition for `Agency@Buyer, Agency@Shipto, Agency@billtoParty` if the value will be **AGIIS-EBID** or **EAN**

I mean in the soap request always Buyer,Shipto, billtoparty can have different sequence like `Buyer=AGIIS-EBID,Shipto=EAN,billtoparty=AGIIS-EBID or Buyer=EAN,Shipto=EAN,billtoparty=AGIIS-EBID or Buyer=AGIIS-EBID,Shipto=EAN,billtoparty=EAN`

I was thinking to do something like this

```
<xsl:when test="($Buyer='AGIIS-EBID' and  $Shipto='AGIIS-EBID' and $Billto='AGIIS-EBID') or ($Buyer='AGIIS-EBID' and  $Shipto='EAN' and $Billto='AGIIS-EBID')($Buyer='AGIIS-EBID' and  $Shipto='AGIIS-EBID' and $Billto='EAN') or ($Buyer='EAN' and  $Shipto='EAN' and $Billto='EAN')">
```

Can anyone please advise for different approach?

Update for the questions.

@michael.hor257k I am sorry.. three agency objects (Buyer, ShipTo and BillToParty), You are correct it can be positive ( AGIIS-EBID or EAN).. If it is positive I need to accept the message, however if its negative I need to reject the message saying @Agency didn't match the AGIIS or EAN for buyer and Shipto and Billparty.

The problem I am facing is Agency objects `(Buyer, ShipTo and BillToParty)` should match `( AGIIS-EBID or EAN)`, but in what manner they come I don't know.

**Below are the different ways values may get assigned.**

Eg: (`Buyer='AGIIS-EBID'and Shipto='EAN'and Billtoparty='AGIIS-EBID') or (Buyer='EAN' and Shipto='EAN' and Billtoparty='AGIIS-EBID') or (Buyer='AGIIS-EBID' and Shipto='EAN' and Billtoparty='EAN'`)` so on ....

One more thing I want to add I have to check the positive condition for `@Agency` in **Buyer and Shipto and BilltoParty**

Comment: I don't think your question is clear enough. You seem to have three agency objects (Buyer, ShipTo and BillToParty), and each one of these can be either positive (i.e. it is either AGIIS-EBID or EAN) or negative (i.e. it is something else). What you're not telling us is what your final test should look for: all of them being positive, at least one of them being positive, something else altogether ...?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have updated the question again. Hopefully this makes things more clear. I have to test every time @((Buyer and ShipTo and BillToParty) to positive ( AGIIS-EBID or EAN) if success route the message to backend. If negative reject the message.

Comment: I am afraid I still don't understand what you want.

Comment: @michael.hor257k My goal to test every time $Buyer= 'AGIIS-EBID' or 'EAN' and $Shipto= 'AGIIS-EBID' or 'EAN' and $Billto= 'AGIIS-EBID' or 'EAN'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal to test every time $Buyer= 'AGIIS-EBID' or 'EAN' and $Shipto=
>   'AGIIS-EBID' or 'EAN' and $Billto= 'AGIIS-EBID' or 'EAN'

Okay, so why don't you just spell that out as;

```
<xsl:when test="
($Buyer='AGIIS-EBID' or $Buyer='EAN') 
and 
($Shipto='AGIIS-EBID' or $Shipto='EAN')
and 
($Billto='AGIIS-EBID' or $Billto='EAN')">
```

Comment: Thank you and my apology for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<xsl:variable name="Buyer_ok" select=" $Buyer = 'EAN' or $Buyer = 'AGIIS-EBID' " />
<xsl:variable name="Shipto_ok" select=" $Shipto = 'EAN' or $Shipto = 'AGIIS-EBID' " />
<xsl:variable name="Billto_ok" select=" $Billto = 'EAN' or $Billto = 'AGIIS-EBID' " />
        :
        :
<xsl:when test=" $Buyer_ok and $Shipto_ok and $Billto_ok "> . . .</xsl:when>
```